# Capturing a web pages http requests via the console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, http, console, nightmare

Using nightmareJS, built on top of electron, which provides a clean API for doing headless browsing and I'm attempting to capture from data from an HTTP request sent by the page when clicking the button. This is easily doable manually by visiting the page, logging in, clicking a button then looking for the request sent in chrome's network tab.

Certainly, because I'm trying to do this both headlessly and programatically, I need some way to capture the http request sent by the page after clicking the button. As far as I can tell, nightmareJS's API does not provide me a means of doing this, but I can very easily  execute arbitrary javascript in the headless browser's console which gives me hope.

If there are other libraries that would more easily enable this functionality, please recommend them; I am by no means tied down to nightmareJS.

Thanks ahead of time.

Answer (score 0):

It *really* depends on what your needs are.  If I'm reading your requirements right, you'll likely want to take a look at [`webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders`](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/web-request.md#webrequestonbeforesendheadersfilter-listener), [`webRequest.onBeforeRequest`](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/web-request.md#webrequestonbeforerequestfilter-listener), and Nightmare's [`.action()`](https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare#nightmareactionname-electronactionelectronnamespace-actionnamespace) method.  The first two let you get the outgoing HTTP request information, the latter will let you define a custom method to capture the events from Nightmare.

If all you're after is logging, the above will suffice.  If you need to do actions based on the request data, that is much trickier as the request events are out-of-band from the Nightmare action handlers, and sort of beyond the current scope of this question.  If that is something you need, let me know, I'll edit this answer.

Comment: Looking at [this](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/web-request.md)


I misunderstood by problem previously, as it appears that what I'm trying to capture a response after clicking the button as opposed to the button sending the request that I'm trying to capture. I'm not seeing which of the methods described would actually give me access to the body of the http response. I posted some sample code of the direction I'm taking below. It is not a functional sample as the secondary function passed to onCompleted() has it's "this" value undefined when being invoked.